# How to get the number of threads in the current process on FreeBSD?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, freebsd

I believe no portable solution exists. On linux, we look at /proc//task/, on darwin we use task_threads(). What about FreeBSD?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like kvm_getprocs is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

melisgl is right -- but only if you are using the default thread implementation, where the process' threads are "kernel-visible". (There are other implementations, such as pth, where this may not be true.)

The kernel-visible threads of a process get be counted with kvm_getprocs() using KERN_PROC_PID|KERN_PROC_INC_THREAD (untested). But using the function may require root-privileges :(